# Are Progressive Web Apps fully supported on IOS or am I doing something wrong?

Tags: ios, manifest, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I started out by developing on Windows/Chrome and testing in Android/Chrome. My PWA also works in Mac/Chrome as far as I know. But I've been unable to load the  Manifest file or Service Worker in IOS 11.2.5 on iPhone and iPad.

I enabled remote debugging on the iPad to find some errors but to no avail. However, I did notice that neither file was loaded under the Network tab.

I've gone on to discover that Manifest files might only be supported in IOS 13, according to [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=web-app-manifest) and that also seems to be the same for [Service Workers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=serviceworkers), can anyone confirm this?

tl;dr: Are Service Workers and Manifest files supported in IOS? and if so are they supported  < IOS 11.3?

Comment: According to WebKit, Service Workers are available in "Preview": https://webkit.org/status/#specification-service-workers This means Safari Technology Preview for MacOS and presumably the betas of iOS 11.3. Manifest is listed as "In Development": https://webkit.org/status/#specification-web-app-manifest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Service workers are not yet fully supported in iOS Devices.  Your project will still work as per normal website but without the added benefits of the service workers.  Until iOS 11.3 comes out to the public, we are still left clueless of what is and what is not supported in service workers.

Answer (score 1):

From ios version 12.2 beta 2 onward, apple brought more support for PWA, where they addressed the following issues.

Web share

> PWAs in the new iOS version are able to activate the native share
>   menu. So you are able to share links in the form of text, audio and
>   video files instantly and easily and forward them to e.g. your friends
>   in other apps.

PWAs don’t forget anymore

> PWAs under iOS 12.2 that you have placed on your home screen can keep
>   their current state in the background. For example, if you open a PWA,
>   exit it and call it up again a little later, it will show you exactly
>   where you left the app before. Before iOS 12.2 Beta 1 it was not
>   possible for PWAs to keep their state and had to be reloaded over and
>   over again.

Links can be called within the PWA

> With iOS 12.2 you call up an external link and stay inside your PWA
>   and don’t “leave” the web app environment. This is due to the fact
>   that a so called in-app browser switches in between and offers you the
>   optimal PWA experience. Until now, a link has been opened in a new
>   Safari tab, which offers you the possibility to return to the PWA (via
>   Back button).

Navigating through gestures

> If, for example, you have opened an area in your PWA and would like to
>   go back a step, you can now do so by wiping the display. This makes
>   sense if there is no Back button on the screen. So you can switch from
>   one page to the next within the PWA environment. This makes the
>   handling of PWAs under iOS 12.2 much more user-friendly compared to
>   before.

https://medium.com/@firt/pwas-on-ios-12-2-beta-the-good-the-bad-and-the-not-sure-yet-if-good-a37b6fa6afbf